# is posible to render wtf.form_field with out label?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, forms, flask

I am using flask with bootstrap, and I need to create a field without the label, since I will be putting it as a placeholder, that way save space in the UI, since this field appears several times.

```
{{ wtf.form_field(field) }}
```

I don't want Label Field, just the actual field that the user will type his information.

Answer (score 3):

Coming to this a bit late but I find the easiest way is to use CSS to set the visibility of the label to None.

```
.control-label {
display: none;
```

}

The above CSS will make all labels invisible. This may not be desirable for every label but if add a "no-label" class  to specific WTF form fields (or indeed a higher element that groups the fields) the following CSS will not display the labels for those fields:

```
.no-label .control-label {
display: none;
```

}

Answer (score 2):

You're using a bootstrap-themed macro to render the `wtform` object, there's no reason you can't create your own customized macro based off that existing one, that does exactly the same thing except without the `.label` rendering.

For instance, the code for the macro you're using is [located on github](https://github.com/mbr/flask-bootstrap/blob/master/flask_bootstrap/templates/bootstrap/wtf.html#L29-L136).  I could copy all of that macro and put it in a new `custom_wtf.html` template file, and rename the macro to be 'wtf_nolabel` and work on adjusting it to my needs.

Lets take lines 83-93 for an example, this seems to render all inline form elements that aren't already handled above:

```
{%- if form_type == "inline" %}
    {{field.label(class="sr-only")|safe}}
    {% if field.type == 'FileField' %}
      {{field(**kwargs)|safe}}
{% else %}
```

I could just remove the `{{ field.label(class="sr-only")|safe }}` line and that would now work for the inline elements, moving down below the code noted, I'd remove line 97-99 to adjust the horizontal rendering option as it's currently:

```
{{field.label(class="control-label " + (
  " col-%s-%s" % horizontal_columns[0:2]
))|safe}}
```

If your form element is just one particular type of input, you could build your own reduced macro that just targets that form element.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not minded to edit the template macros as outlined by [@Doobeh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49037704/2800058) and you don't want to show any field labels you could use the following technique.

Create a "No Label" mixin class that sets the label property of all form fields to `None`.

```
class NoLabelMixin(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(NoLabelMixin, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field_name in self._fields:
            field_property = getattr(self, field_name)
            field_property.label = None

class MyForm(Form):
    first_name = StringField(u'First Name', validators=[validators.input_required()])
    last_name  = StringField(u'Last Name', validators=[validators.optional()])

class MyNoLabelForm(NoLabelMixin, MyForm):
    pass

my_no_label_form = MyNoLabelForm()
```

Answer (score 2):

With that in the template file, all labels are hidden and space is free:

```
{% block styles %}
{{super()}}
<style>
  .control-label {display: none;}
</style>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 2):

This line will render a form field with hidden label

```
    {{ render_field(form.phone, form_type="inline", class="form-control", placeholder="Phone number")}}
```

Here is the output rendered:

```
    <div class="form-group required">
    <label class="sr-only" for="phone">Phone</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Phone Number" required="" type="text" value="">
    </div>
```

label is class="sr-only" which is hidden.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply set the label to an empty String when creating the Form class in python.

```
class form_field(Form):
    field = StringField( label='')
```

Here it is in the [documentation](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.x/fields/), though not well explained.

It says;
"When you override a Field’s constructor, to maintain consistent behavior, you should design your constructor so that:

You take label=’‘, validators=None as the first two positional arguments"

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late but I was having the same issue as OP as I just Wanted the field (no labels). In WTForms==2.3.3 and Flask==1.1.2 its is simple as accessing the inner field.

```
        {% for field in form.cities %}
        {{ wtf.form_field(field.city)}}
        {% endfor %}
```

So in OP's case it would be field.name where name is the varibale name in you form class.

Answer (score -1):

instead creating a new macro and new classes

1) did a css style that hide the labels at the beginning of the page so they don't show

```
<style>
.my_div_class label{
 visibility: hidden;
}
</style>
```

2) a javascript that delete all labels below my wanted div that runs document.ready

```
        var all = hold.getElementsByTagName("LABEL");
        for (var i=0; i < all.length; i++){
            var parent = all[i].parentElement;
            parent.removeChild(all[i])
            }
        }
```

might not be the best practice but was very simple to do and very quick, posting it since its simple,  I might need to remember it for later, and doesn't need to have a depth knowledge of bootstrap and flask forms. hope it helps

Answer (score -1):

even easier!

```
<style>
label{
  display: None;
}
</style>
```

this was so simple

Comment: this would hide all labels in page. yikes!

Comment: it does answer the question,  don't render the labels,  and is easier than rewriting the jinja wtf form template macro

Comment: Not really.  I still renders the labels but just hides them (and *all* labels) afterwards.  This would affect not just the labels related to the wtf form template but **any** and all labels on the entire DOM (HTML/document)

Comment: render mean show in the page(not related on what's in the code), he didn't ask about particular labels but If that is the case the user need to just hide certain labels, he can use classes and ids,    such      .my_class label...

Comment: That's not what render means but whatever... In any case, my point is that this would affect all labels so this is not a great suggestion which is why is voted down